# How to separate large dataframes and save it to new smaller dataframes and export it to csv files in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have an excel file contains 129000 row and I want to separate this file into csv files of size 5000 rows and export it, any help?

Comment: You can export as CSV from Excel

Comment: I assume you're using Pandas, so I added the [tag:pandas] tag for you. If that's incorrect, you can [edit] to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
mino=df.index.min()
maxo=df.index.max()
ran = [i for i in range(mino,maxo,5000)]


for i in tqdm(range(len(ran))):
    if i+1 == len(ran):
        val1 = ran[i]
        val2 = maxo
    else:
        val1 = ran[i]
        val2 = ran[i+1] - 1
    df.loc[val1:val2,:].to_csv('chunck{0}.csv'.format(i))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with pandas and np split array method:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# read excel file
file = pd.read_excel('your_file.xls')

# split the resulting df into chunks 5,000 each or less
chunks = np.split(file, range(5000, file.shape[0], 5000))

# save each to csv, here we use index of array as a file name
for index, data  in enumerate(chunks):
    data.to_csv(f'file{index}.csv', index=False)
```